# how to document private variable in phpdoc

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

I am trying to document the private variable in phpdoc but its not documenting.

Here is my code:

```
class Content
{
    /**
    * simple db class variable
    * @access private
    */
    var $_db = null; // db
    private $_s3 = null; // s3

    /**
    * queue for mainting session queue1
    */
    public $queue = array();
}
```

The `$_db` and `$_s3` both are not coming in documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's what supposed to happen - setting `@access private` prevents the following code block from appearing in the documentation.

To get it to appear you need to use the command line switch `--parseprivate`

See http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.access.pkg.html

Comment: It's actually -pp or --parseprivate, but otherwise this answer is correct.  Private items are not included in documentation by default.